# can someone please help me find a copy of davka hebrew english mishnah berurah

Tags: mishnah-berurah

the company davka used to make a program called "Hebrew English Mishnah Berurah for windows" but stopped producing it around when windows 7 came out because apparently it was not running well on windows 7 and up and they decided to not update it anymore.

no stores carry it and davka said they dont produce/have it anymore. they told me if i can find a copy i am welcome to copy it (i have an old pc running windows xp)

so if anyone has this or knows someone who has it, (or knows of any store that still has a copy i could buy,) it would be a huge chessed for me, as i am trying to make worksheets for learning MB.

P.S. i am aware of sefaria and for various reasons it is not suitable for my needs. (besides for the fact that siman 47 which is the main part i am working on right now is completely untranslated lol)

ty!

Comment: My impression of davka is they sell expensive products that were useful at the time they were released, but the functionality is now mostly available with free services like sefaria.   Their model just doesn't work so well anymore.

Comment: you are not incorrect. this piece of software was really unique, however, as it had the mishna berurah text, selectable, plus the correct tzuras hadaf, plus really good translation, and it was complete, and printable with only certain sections of the page selected, and it would print out just the selected area WITH tzuras hadaf! it is odd, to me at least, that they stopped updating it, there is no competing product. what's even crazier though is that they claim the software is lost, as they lost all their extant copies and dont have the original program anywhere. why would a company do that?

Comment: A quick Bing search led me to this link: http://www.bmsoftware.com/mishnahberurahhe.htm It looks like a super old-fashioned and out of date site, but arguably that's what they specialize in... They have a phone number, so you can always call and ask if they have what you want.

Comment: Well, in my search on the internet for your Mishnah Berurah I did find you(?) on [The Hebrew Cafe](http://www.thehebrewcafe.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=5240&pid=50547#pid50547) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/7dfq0u/davka_hebrew_english_mishnah_berurah_for_windows/).

Comment: i called bmsoftware, they said they dont have it :( and yes the hebrew cafe and reddit are me lol